# How to rerun the DOMContentLoaded event in javascript

Tags: javascript

So, I have some code that will execute on `DOMContentLoaded` with an event listener. Is there anyway to trick the code into rerunning that code without reloading the entire page?

Comment: Extract the logic into a secondary method.  Call the method from the DOMContentLoaded event handler.  Call it other places to make it repeat.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a bit hard, but try to use this function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent